# Ruby on Rails multi select dropdown

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Firstly, I need to implement this HTML form in Rails, its a dropdown of languages that can be multi-selected. Secondly, what is the best approach to store the multiple languages selected by the user?

```
<div class="button-group">
  <label class="form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">Language <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span> </label>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu2 dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="small" data-value="" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" /> No Other Language</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="small" data-value="arabic" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" /> Arabic</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="small" data-value="french" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" /> French</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="small" data-value="spanish" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" /> Spanish</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to do it on DB level, create model of Language, and use has many through, user had many languages , language has many user , than add data for language as much as you want, in the select box, only load those languages which are added in database

Comment: for multi-select try `<%= f.select :languages, options_for_select([["english",1],["Arabic",2],["German",3]]), {}, {:multiple => true, :class => "your class", :style => "styles;" } %>` with integration of **select2** as @Vishal mentioned maintain a languages model and maintain a `UserLanguage` model for storing the relations between users and languages like this you can get user to language and language to user associations.

Comment: Two approaches. 1. Store languages for a user in database (if you want to persist their selection across sessions and browsers) 2. Use session to store the selected laguages (in other cases). I will leave the implementation details to you.

Answer (score 0):

- First to store the multiple values of the Users Languages, create a Language model that has a one-to-many relationship with the User model.

  ```
  class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
         belongs_to :user
  end
  ```
- To store the options of the Languages you can create an enum in the Users model:

  ```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
         has_many :languages
         enum language: {:english=>1, :arabic=>2, :french=>3, :spanish=>4}
  end
  ```
- And to add the multiselect in the form try (also a nice alternative is using check_box):

  ```
  <%= f.select :languages, {}, User.languages.each { |k, v| [k, v]}, :multiple => true %>
  ```

  <% User.languages.each do |k, v| %>
       <%= check_box :languages, k.humanize, value: v %>
       <%= label :languages, k.humanize %>
  <% end %>